# check for last error in LXSOCKET (iphone)

Tags: objective-c, c

hi i am using lxscoket in iPhone to create sockets for iPhone. but here i am unable to find the last error which occurred.i am trying to use [err code] to find the error but it is not giving the error. so can any one please guide me in this.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using the `errno` present in `<sys/errno.h>` we can find the last error.